# Problem running <<flutter pub run build_runner build >>for JSON from/to generation

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter.
I'm trying to use the `flutter pub run build_runner build` command to generate `json serializers` using json annotation `JsonSerializable()`.

When I run the command, then error is displayed several times:

```
...\\flutter\\bin\\cache\\pkg\\sky_engine\\lib\\ui\\compositing.dart:nnn:nn - This requires the 'super-parameters' language feature to be enabled.
```

---

```
flutter doctor:
 No issues found!

flutter --version
Flutter 3.7.0 • channel stable 

Framework • revision b06b8b2710 (9 days ago) 

Engine • revision b24591ed32

Tools • Dart 2.19.0 • DevTools 2.20.1
```

My class is annotated:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
part 'HttpErrorResponse.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class HttpErrorResponse{
  late final String type;
  late final String title;
  late final int status;
  late final String detail;
  late final String instance;
}
```

I'm trying to build a WEB Application

My `pubspec.yml` file has:

```
environment:
sdk: '\>=2.18.4 \<3.0.0'
...
dependencies
...
json_annotation: ^4.3.0
dev_dependencies
...
json_serializable: ^6.3.1
```

I tried `json_anotation ^4.8.0`, No success,

`json_serializable ^6.0.0` and `^6.6.0`, No success

I added `use_super_parameters`

to the lint rules in the `analysis_options.yml` file on my project directory with no joy.

I also run

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

No success

Comment: Have you tried with flutter clean?

Comment: Yes, I did >flutter clean, nothing improved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the JSON generation problem by using OpenApi generator for Dart

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dart run build_runner build
```